# What is the flight attitude of a Partenavia/Vulcanair P68?

Tags: attitude

Planning to fit a camera into a Partenavia P68 for vertical (nadir) imagery, and would like to know the difference between ground and 'normal' flight attitude within 2-3°.

I'm a pilot, and familiar with mainly with Cessna 172/182/206 official flight attitude (i.e. levelling point above the door, or by screws on fuselage) - seems like, in comparison, P68 sits on the ground in pretty much the same angle as it would be in flight, but can't find any confirmation of this.

What is the normal levelling line used? (While attitude can certainly vary with W&B, airspeed and flaps used, I'm interested for now in the 'official' levelling you might find in the POH)

Comment: How critical is this, what is the tolerance you need to achieve?

Comment: Attitude varies in the same airplane depending on weight, balance, and airspeed. There's no single answer.

Comment: If I needed a constant nadir direction for a project, I'd just use a [gyro stabilization system](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4rC3D1HqU4), this can be rented and there are cheaper devices.